# How can I mock my environment variables for my pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic, pytest-mock-patch

I've looked at some examples to mock environment variables.
[Here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/10/13/how-to-mock-environment-variables-with-pytest/)

In my case, I have to mock a variable in my `config.py` file that is setup as follows:

```
class ServiceConfig(BaseSettings):
   ...
   API_AUDIENCE: str = os.environ.get("API_AUDIENCE")
   ... 
   ...
```

I have that called here:

```
class Config(BaseSettings):  
auth: ClassVar[ServiceConfig] = ServiceConfig()
```

I've attempted to patch that value as follows:

```
@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"API_AUDIENCE": "https://mock.com"})
class Test(TestCase):
```

Another way I've tried is:

```
@patch('config.Config.API_AUDIENCE', "https://mock.com")
def ....:
```

The setup is incorrect both ways, getting this error:

```
E   pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for 
ServiceConfig
E   API_AUDIENCE
```

What is the correct way to setup mocking an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the environment, and restore it after the test:

```py
import os
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture()
def setenvvar(monkeypatch):
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, clear=True):
        envvars = {
            "API_AUDIENCE": "https://mock.com",
        }
        for k, v in envvars.items():
            monkeypatch.setenv(k, v)
        yield # This is the magical bit which restore the environment after
```

This is just a fixture, you can use it (or not) in any test you want, at the scope you want, no extra dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setenv`:

```
def test_something(self, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("API_AUDIENCE", "https://mock.com")
    importlib.reload(conf)
    assert "mock" in Config.auth
```

Comment: IMHO, this isn't goint to work because it would be monkeypatching the ENV variable **after** the `API_AUDIENCE` is defined in `ServiceConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `pytest-env`. Install this package, and in your toml file you can add the following section:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
env = [
    "KEY = VALUE",
]
```

A second option, one that is also mentioned in the link you provided, is `monkeypatch`.

```
def test_function(monkeypatch, ...):
    monkeypatch.setattr(`<class>', "<attribute>", <mock_value>)
    ....
```